# two empty list for list comprehension

Tags: python, list, list-comprehension

How can I do such code in list comprehension ??

```py
from itertools import combinations
remove_list = []
reamin_list = []
for m,n in combinations([0,1,2,3,4,0,1],2):
    if (m or n) in remove_list:
        continue
    else:
        if (m+n)%2 == 0:
            reamin_list.append(m)
            reamin_list.append(n)
        else:
            remove_list.append(m)
            remove_list.append(n)
```

Thanks you a lot

Comment: While in principle you could write this using a comprehension, it would be an unreadable mess. Comprehensions are really for simple maps and filters.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I'm pretty sure `if (m or n) in remove_list` doesn't do what you think it does

Comment: I am trying to apply this loop to `joblib` for `Parallel`, so I ask such idiot question. LOL